# Weird Linux sort results when $(dollar sign) is encountered

Tags: linux, sorting

When I tried to sort the following text by `sort test.txt`

test.txt

```
fadf
basdf
asdfa
asdf
tasdf
gasdf
$
$ asdf
$ basd
$ asfd
$sdfa
$asdf
```

The output is:

```
$
asdf
$asdf
$ asdf
asdfa
$ asfd
$ basd
basdf
fadf
gasdf
$sdfa
tasdf
```

Btw, on my mac, the output is:

```
$
$ asdf
$ asfd
$ basd
$asdf
$sdfa
asdf
asdfa
gasdf
sdf
tasdf
```

I think the result is weird, except the position for $ sign, even "asdf" and "asdfa" are separated by $ lines.

Why are those $ not together? And How to make them together(or how to sort by ASCII)? Is this a bug?

(I've searched for a long time. Many thanks~)

Linux: 14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr
sort: (GNU coreutils) 8.21

Comment: The place to start looking is in your locale environment variables.

Comment: What's your `locale` on the machines?

Comment: If you mean this:$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Your mac uses the FreeBSD version of sort, btw.

Comment: Oh~, but how can I fix this on Linux? It causes a fatal error when I was handling a huge file with a single $ line. I tried changing $ into # or % just now, the same thing happened. Thanks, Thomas, choroba and crafter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the unexpected sort is the sort rules.

To see what you current rules are, type

```
sort  --debug sortfile
```

On my laptop, for example, I get

```
sort: using ‘en_ZA.UTF-8’ sorting rules

$
_
asdf
____
$asdf
_____
$ asdf
______
asdfa
_____
$ asfd
```

So it is using a collocation using my locale, which will include rules to be aware of currency and such.

To ignore this, change your collation to the legacy collation C.

```
 LC_COLLATE=C sort  sortfile 
$
$ asdf
$ asfd
$ basd
$asdf
$sdfa
asdf
asdfa
basdf
fadf
gasdf
tasdf
```

If you want the settings permanant, you can set the locale in your bashrc file, but this *may* effect other things like file listings etc.

Comment: Thanks @crafter. That's exactly the problem. But the case is I am writing a perl program. Sorting is one of the key process. Since the target file is really huge. I save part of the file on disk and sort step by step. So if I use bash sort, it means the compatibility will be very bad. I'm think about using sort in perl to do that.(At first I don't want to do so because there is bash sort...) Any other suggestion from you~?

Comment: Perl is excellent in sorting. You should try that too. I would expect Perl to display the same locale effect as bash (untested). However, I expect bash to be faster.  Do 'man sort' to see the options for sort. You can set the memory size using the -S option.(untested).

Comment: Cool, Thank you very much @crafter!